# How to provide multiple values for a xs:simpleType?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsd-validation

So I'm currently working on an XSD-file which contains a simpleType called `ipaddress`:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="ipaddress">
    <xs:restriction base ="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

This one works well for all ip addresses I use.
But I want the ipaddress to accept either the ipaddress itself or the string "localhost". How do I do that? I already tried things like this

```
 <xs:simpleType name="ipaddress">
    <xs:restriction base ="xs:string">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"/>    
            <xs:enumeration value="localhost"/>
      <xs:choice>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

or like that

```
  <xs:complexType name="ipaddress">    
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" type="xs:string"/>   
            <xs:enumeration value="localhost" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:choice>    
  </xs:complexType>
```

but none of these solutions work when validating my xml file against the xsd schema. I think I'm right by using `xs:choice` by I don't know how - I'm at the very beginning of learning XSD and I'm still a bit confused of all these tags and elements and how to connect them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [W3C page on `xs:restriction`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-xmlschema11-2-20110721/datatypes.html#rf-pattern) you can use multiple `xs:pattern`s in one `xs:restriction`:

> Note: An XML  containing more than one  element gives rise to a single ·regular expression· in the set; this ·regular expression· is an "or" of the ·regular expressions· that are the content of the  elements.

So the following does work:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ipaddress">
  <xs:restriction base ="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"/>                                
    <xs:pattern value="localhost"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think choice is for complex types, for your simple type restriction you can simply add another pattern

```
<xs:simpleType name="ipaddress">
    <xs:restriction base ="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"/>
        <xs:pattern value="localhost"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```